# How to make php connection as public connection in order to access it from anywhere

Tags: php, odbc

this is the current connection file i have use,i was thinking to make the connection public so that i could easily to get connection everywhere,but i have no idea on how to write it.

```html
<?php

define ("DB_HOST", "AccDatabase2"); // set database host

define ("DB_USER", "ers"); // set database user

define ("DB_PASS","ers"); // set database password

define ("DB_NAME","AccDatabase2"); // set database name



$link_mssql = odbc_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save this code in a connect.php file.

connect.php

```
<?php 
define ("DB_HOST", "AccDatabase2"); // set database host 
define ("DB_USER", "ers"); // set database user 
define ("DB_PASS","ers"); // set database password 
define ("DB_NAME","AccDatabase2"); // set database name   
$link_mssql = odbc_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
```

Then include it in other files according to the path where you store the file.

```
index.php
<?php 
include_once('connect.php');

echo 'included connection';
```